Is it reliable to use pthread_self() to get a thread ID even from C++ threads?
On Linux, libstdc++ doesn't use pthread_create() to create threads, as it can be seen from this bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218607 (libpsx wraps pthread_create() to intercept thread creation, but that doesn't work on C++ threads which can only mean libstdc++ doesn't use pthread_create()).
I'm not here to report bugs or anything like that, so now that this little bit of context was introduced, let's go to my actual question.
For the architecture of my software, I need a thread ID. The thread might have been created from C libraries or C++ libraries. I don't control that. A function (callback) that I wrote (so some code that I do control) is called from such thread. I need to get a thread ID from this callback.
Requirements for my thread ID:

The ID needs to be unique (no two live threads can share the same ID).
It's okay if ID recycling happens once threads die.
I need to be able to "serialize" this ID in a C struct. As in... a memcpy() from the ID will yield another meaningful copy of the same ID (the IDs compare equal) as long as the underlying thread stays alive (as I said earlier, recycling thread IDs once threads die are not a problem for my architecture).

So my question is: is it reliable to use pthread_self() from C++/libstdc++ threads? In case pthread_self() is not reliable to call from C++ threads, do you suggest an alternative approach for generating a thread ID?
A little bit more of context: I'm creating a capsicum sandbox on FreeBSD (I'm doing something very very similar on Linux with Landlock+seccomp so glibc/libstdc++ problems also matter to me... hence this question), but I wish to reuse existing C/C++ libraries. Capsicum fully disables ambient authority. I'm wrapping libc functions that acquire resources from ambient authority. My libc function overriders send messages over an UNIX unnamed socket to a supervisor that lives outside the sandbox. Given any thread might use these functions, the request includes the thread ID (hence the need to be able to serialize the thread ID in a C struct) and blocks the thread until the matching reply is received.

Why not just std::this_thread::get_id()?  Apologies if I've missed something in the question.  Aside from that the pthread_self documentation states: "This function always succeeds, returning the calling thread's ID.".

If you don't know how the threads were created, what makes you think that you can get the thread id via pthread_self? You have to make sure, that all parties use the same thread implementation (C++ threads or pthreads), then use the respective getter for the id.

libstdc++ does use pthread_create on POSIX systems. There is a wrapper around the posix thread API that is used directly by libstdc++ called "gthreads". The API is implemented (mostly by forwarding to corresponding pthread functions) in libgcc with different configuration depending on platform. See e.g.  https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/gthr-posix.h and various specific arch config files.

The kernel tid (gettid syscall) is unique (system-wide).

"I'm wrapping libc functions that acquire resources from ambient authority.": Read the comments in the linked POSIX implementation for libgcc. For some C library implementations, including glibc, it does sometimes call into implementation details directly (but not for pthread_create). I don't know what exactly you want to wrap, but that might require some modification of the gthread implementation.

@G.M., if I use std::this_thread::get_id(), then my question changes to: is it reliable to use std::this_thread::get_id() from POSIX threads? I'm using external C/C++ libraries and I don't control how they might create threads (sorry if it wasn't clear enough from the question).

@G.M., I believe the POSIX manpage you refer to is only relevant to check for errno values. It's not relevant to know whether the pthread_t is valid for threads created from libstdc++.

@vinipsmaker If you don't want to depend on implementation details of libraries, you can write against the Linux syscall API directly as suggested above (gettid).

@CraigEstey, the same project builds under Linux and FreeBSD (in fact, very little code changes... aside from kqueue/epoll stuff). I'd rather avoid direct syscalls if possible (but I'll do it if there's no way around it).

@user17732522, so libstdc++ does in fact use pthreads (even if it doesn't call pthread_create() directly?). That should answer my question (it is reliable to use pthread_self() even from C++ threads). I'll try to think of some code to test this assertion. If you provide the whole trail/sources for the implementation, that'd be an acceptable answer for the question I posed here regarding the reliability of pthread_self() from C++ threads.

@user17732522 I don't know what exactly you want to wrap, but that might require some modification of the gthread implementation. I'm not wrapping pthreads. I'm wrapping C/POSIX functions such as open(), connect() etc... functions that acquire resources out of addressable system objects (namespaces). I'm using the __wrap_ linker/loader trick to wrap these functions.

gettid is a syscall under FreeBSD. Note that any and all wrapper libraries [ultimately] must use kernel tid to communicate with the kernel that creates the thread. As to wrappers, it's [somewhat] insane to not wrap on top of pthreads. g(libc) knows about pthreads, and the wrapper layer [probably] uses libc functions, so having something that doesn't [ultimately] use pthreads is problematic (e.g. when we try to use atexit or the cleanup pthreads does during fork/exec). pthreads does a lot with (e.g.) signal masks, etc that c++ would be crazy to "go direct" to [linux] clone

Since your "watchdog" process supervisor is outside the memory of the process/threads you're talking about, the only thing it can know about is a kernel tid. Passing the return of pthread_t self = pthread_self() [or whatever a given wrapper layer uses] via the socket isn't too meaningful. And can become stale when the thread terminates--a race condition unless you send a " terminated" message (which isn't guaranteed)). The supervisor can always cross-check with tkill(tid,0)

It seems FreeBSD has thr_self() (not gettid()): https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=thr_self&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+14.1-RELEASE+and+Ports

@CraigEstey, the “watchdog” doesn't need to understand the thread-ID. From its POV, it's just a cookie value it must copy back into the reply. As long as we can memcpy() into bytes over an UNIX socket, the ID will be safe to use in this architecture.

Re. thr_self, I was talking about the syscall (and FreeBSD does have __NR_gettid). See my rant about gettid glibc wrapper: GCC warns about gettid() syscall wrapper, with glibc 2.30-8

At this point I'm considering creating a thread_local variable to access from my callback and using the address for this variable (so an uintptr_t) as the thread-ID.

It's okay if ID recycling happens once threads die Consider: Your variable has address 0x1234. Thread terminates. New thread created. It's per-thread area is the same address, so that your variable for the new thread still has address 0x1234. It sends message with this ID (0x1234). How does supervisor see that first thread terminated and it's dealing with a new thread (in the new message)? Maybe you should post some of your code? If you don't care about this now, will you ever in the future?

@CraigEstey, I can post some code once it's more readable. Re: about your scenario: the sender sends (SOCK_SEQPACKET) the request (with thread-ID), and blocks the thread (read() or pthread_cond_wait()) until the reply with the matching ID is received. Under this protocol, the thread ID stays valid while I'm using it because the referenced thread is blocked in a call until the reply is read back (and the ID is no longer used afterwards so we don't care). The supervisor only uses the ID as a cookie. It's the sandboxed process who is responsible for dispatching based on the ID. No race here


Is it reliable to use pthread_self() to get a thread ID even from C++ threads?

It depends on what characteristics you want to rely upon.  If you're on a POSIX system, then it is safe to call pthread_self(), and it always succeeds.  But when such a call occurs in a C++ program, neither POSIX nor C++ defines any relationship between the resulting pthread_t and the properties of the std::thread in whose context the call occurs.  Not even that you will get different results from calls in different std::threads.
You might discover such a relationship empirically, but that would not be safe to rely upon.  You might find a relationship documented by your C++ implementation, and that would be safe to rely upon in the context of that implementation, but such reliance would constitute a portability issue.
You write:

For the architecture of my software, I need a thread ID. The thread might have been created from C libraries or C++ libraries. I don't control that. A function (callback) that I wrote (so some code that I do control) is called from such thread. I need to get a thread ID from this callback.

The problem there is that "thread" is not well enough defined in those specifications.  You need to either know or be told what kind of thread you need an ID for, so that you can use an appropriate mechanism to get an ID. And if you need to accommodate different kinds of threads in the same program then you have extra work to do.
One way forward would be to require pthreads use, including in C++ programs.  That's no big deal for a C++ implementation that uses pthreads and maintains a stable 1:1 relationship between std::threads and pthreads. With any other kind of C++ implementation, however, it would likely manifest unwanted behavior in C++ programs that use std::thread.
That nevertheless seems natural to me for a system on which pthreads is considered the one and only native thread library.  To the extent that it is sensitive to threading, a container / sandbox such as you describe should be expected to operate in terms of native threads.  If that causes issues for applications that use a different threading scheme then you could reasonably (according to me) say that's someone else's problem.
